# Including model name in response

Tags: python, django, json, django-rest-framework

Pending solution but all I'm seeing is that I need to actually create a custom Renderer as per the doc here -

http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers

I know this as going by the same data in XML output in the file "renderers.py" there is an XMLRenderer

If I change, using the example below, "list-item" to be the table/model name I get the output I want so I'm going to investigate creating a custom renderer.

I have a json output that looks like this -

```
{

    "trgmst_id": 224,
    "trgjob_id": 22652,
    "jobmst_id": 10079,
    "trgjob_order": 2,
    "trgjob_type": 0,
    "trgjob_level": 0

}
```

But instead I want it to look like this -

```
{
  "trgjob": {
    "trgmst_id": 224,
    "trgjob_id": 22652,
    "jobmst_id": 10079,
    "trgjob_order": 2,
    "trgjob_type": 0,
    "trgjob_level": 0
  }
}
```

How do I get my serializer or view to include the model name?

Here is my serializer -

```
class TrgjobSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Trgjob
```

Here is my view -

```
@csrf_exempt
def trgjob_detail(request, pk):
    """
    Retrieve, update or delete a code snippet.
    """
    try:
        DEV = Trgjob.objects.using('database1').filter(jobmst_id=pk)
    except Trgjob.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=404)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = TrgjobSerializer(DEV, many=True)
        return JSONResponse(serializer.data)
```

And here is the JSONResponse -

```
class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):
    """
    An HttpResponse that renders its content into JSON.
    """
    def __init__(self, data, **kwargs):
        content = JSONRenderer().render(data)
        kwargs['content_type'] = 'application/json'
        super(JSONResponse, self).__init__(content, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to construct the desired output in the view. For example

```
from rest_framework.response import Response


def view(request):
    ...
    serializer = TrgJobSerializer(DEV, many=True)
    response = {'trgjob': serializer.data}
    return Response(response)
```

The JSONRenderer will still handle rendering to JSON, e.g. converting `False` to `false` etc.

Comment: Thank you!  This is by far more elegant and seamless!  Did exactly as you had there and the default renderer picked up everything perfectly!